# Business visit to EU for equipment installation

Tags: schengen, germany, eu, australian-citizens, business-travel

I am an Australian resident in the UK, and a partner of a dual UK-EU national, operating a small business. I am exploring undertaking short business visits to install technical equipment on-site at a customer's facility in Germany, over several days. This would occur in 2021 (post-brexit transition).

Do I need any application beyond the Schengen Visa-free access given to Australian nationals?

Comment: While this is a very short visit, the Expatriates Stack Exchange might be able to help regarding working visa. It could depend on the member state.

Comment: You can get advice from expert immigration consultants

Answer (score 2):

As an Australian visiting Germany you are allowed to engage in business activities (but not work in local employment) in Germany when entering on the short-term Schengen visa waiver program.

You must conform the the other requirements of the program which include:

- Not staying in the Schengen area for more than 90 days in any 180 day
  period.
- Having a valid passport issued within the last 10 years with at least 3 months remaining

The European Travel Information and Authorisation System (ETIAS) program may change the process from 2022.

References

https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/en/einreiseundaufenthalt/visabestimmungen-node
https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/en/einreiseundaufenthalt/-/231148
https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/etias/
https://eeas.europa.eu/sites/eeas/files/visa_waiver_faqs_en.pdf

Comment: Installing equipment may not be considered to be a business trip (meetings, signing contracts etc), but a work activity.  This is something that you should clarify.

Comment: It should be noted that the three month period of passport validity is measured from the anticipated date of departure from the Schengen area.  The required validity at the time of entry is therefore more than three months unless the traveler expects to depart on the day of arrival, before midnight.